# How to remove specific characters from strings in sql

Tags: mysql, replace

I've got a table with a column. I want to change a part of some strings in the column.

**Input**

6|Drivers Manuals

BH-EB531

TRST-BACMN-

**Desired output**

Drivers Manuals

BH-EB531

TRST-BACMN

Below was the code I tired to execute

```
 select REPLACE(REPLACE(COL, '6|', ''),'-','') FROM Table
```

**Output**

Drivers Manuals

BHEB531

TRSTBACMN

the script need to remove '6|' and last character only if it was '-'

Can any one help me to achieve desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (
        REPLACE
                (CASE 
                    WHEN RIGHT (COL, 1) = '-' 
                        THEN LEFT(COL, LENGTH(COL) - 1) 
                    ELSE COL
                END, '6|', ''
                )
        )   
FROM Table
```